# OPC UA Milo custom Data Type Structure no codec?

Tags: java, encoding, codec, milo

I tried the example to read a Custom DataType variable value which is defined in another cpp opcua-server, but I still get `no codec registered for encodingId=NodeId{ns=1, id=5554}`. Shall the codecs registration (`registerCustomCodec()` function) be on the client or server side?

In my client, I set up the `dataTypeId` and the `binaryEncodeingId` accordingly:

```
ExpandedNodeId TYPE_ID = new ExpandedNodeId(
        UShort.valueOf(2), "mvn.mvn.de", 5552, UInteger.MIN);
ExpandedNodeId BINARY_ENCODING_ID = new ExpandedNodeId(
        UShort.valueOf(2), "mvn.mvn.de", 5554, UInteger.MIN);    
NodeId dataTypeId = TYPE_ID.toNodeId(client.getNamespaceTable())
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("namespace not found"));
NodeId binaryEncodingId = BINARY_ENCODING_ID.toNodeId(client.getNamespaceTable())
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("namespace not found"));
```

The namespaces URI & Index are the same for the cpp OPC UA server.
Do I miss something?

Comment: The problem is solved!

Comment: How did you solve this issue? Posting problem was solved doesn't help much.